# How to get list of search results of location like in google maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview

I am developing an application in which when the I enters an address ,I fetch latitude and longitude of that address and drop the pin.
But what I want is like I enter any business or address then a list of that search comes in google maps and multiple pins are dropped for that address.
I also want this feature to get include in my app but when I pass my address only one location comes not a list like it comes in google maps.
Please help me if anybody knows how google maps searches a couple of locations for that address

ex:- caribou coffee, chapel hil

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This functionnality is provided by [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/places/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an algorithm it's using the harvesine forumula or a quadtree data structure. A quadtree or a r-tree in maps applications most likely it uses a space-filling-curve to sort the quadtree. If you look for  sfc I recommend a hilbert curve because it has better space fill quality but normally they uses a z-curve.